# Why does my character stop a little before landing on the ground?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, platformer, game-maker

I made a little game with side-scrolling and a box (the player) jumping across the level. The simple physics are almost done, but I have two problem with the way things behave:

- On landing, the box takes a little time to reach the floor
- When the box hit a roof, there is always a little space between it and the object.

Here is my collision code (in the player's Step Event):

```
myGravity = 0.5;
if (vspeed > 10)  vspeed = 10;

speedAir = abs(vspeed+1);

//ON_FLOOR = !(place_free(x, y + speedAir));
ON_AIR = place_free(x, y + speedAir);

FREE_RIGHT = place_free(x + speedScreen, y); 
FREE_UP = place_free(x, y - speedAir);

KEY_UP = keyboard_check(vk_up);
KEY_LEFT = keyboard_check(vk_left);
KEY_RIGHT = keyboard_check(vk_right);
KEY_FIRE = keyboard_check(vk_space);


/* JUMP */
if ON_AIR
{
    gravity = myGravity;
    gravity_direction = 270;

    if !(FREE_UP)
    {
        vspeed = 0;
    }
}


else // if ON_FLOOR
{
    gravity = 0;
    gravity_direction = 270;
    vspeed = 0;

    // JUMP
    if KEY_UP & FREE_UP
    {
        vspeed = -10;
    }
}


/* LATERAL */
if (FREE_RIGHT)
{
    x += speedScreen; // screen side-scrolling
}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The problem

I think the main flaw is that you're checking *if the object is in the air* using the code  `place_free(x, y + speedAir)`. That's effectively like this:

[image: two IN_AIR checks that say no, a third that says yes]

Imagine your object is shaped like that blue J-[tetromino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) and the ghost version of it represents its position + its speed; where it will be next frame. The yellow is a floor.

At the first two speeds, it's correctly determined as being in the air. In the third, the `place_free` check fails because the ghost intersects something, and so `ON_AIR == false` even though the object is nowhere near the ground!

### The fix

It might be worth reading up on [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) ([Metanet's tutorial on separating axis theorem](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) is pretty great), but here's one simple-ish method: To make sure the character stops exactly on the ground, you could first of all check only for `place_free(x, y)`, and use the object's position relative to the ground object to calculate how much they intersect by. Then just move the object out by that amount.

[image: simple collision response]

Comment: Also, take care that objects cannot move through the floor entirely in a single frame.